# Using scrollto horizontally inside a div not in the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal timeline inside a scrollable div and I want to scroll it depending on the date it has.
I've created a `<span>` tag to identify where the div should scroll to. Basically, when it has a `class="scrollTo"`, the scroll should move to there, without moving the whole window. It should scroll only the div.

I tried some suggestion from here, but I don't know if I am doing it right.
I used the following code:

```
$(".timeLineContainer").animate({
   scrollTop: $(".timeLineContainer").scrollTop() + 
       ($(".scrollTo").offset().top - $(".timeLineContainer").offset().top)
});
```

Here is my code in JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/douglasbrca/j2o546wr/2/

Any suggestion based on the code above?

Comment: In your fiddle the scroll is horizontal ...

Comment: Oh! Sorry! That's correct. It's Horizontal, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ok so with this* :

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/j2o546wr/6/

**Js**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".scrollTo").length > 0){
        $(".timeLineContainer").animate({scrollLeft: $(".timeLineContainer").scrollLeft() + ($(".scrollTo").offset().left - $(".timeLineContainer").offset().left)});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked perfectly and I saw the difference.